# Bandmath error when calculating RVI in Landsat data

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8, multi-band

I'm using the `LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA` dataset. Using this I want to calculate the RVI of a region. This is done by dividing the Near Infrared band (B5 in the dataset) by the Red band (B4 in the dataset). I do this by firstly defining both bands as separate variables namely `nir` and `red`. Using this I do the following:

```
var rvi = nir.divide(red)
```

When doing this is keeps giving me the error:

> nir.divide is not a function

Is there any other way to do this bandmath?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fabbbc2aa3288e6b8e1daad980d66655

Answer (score 2):

`nir` is an image collection, and you cannot do band math directly with one.

Depending of what you're trying to do, you either turn the collection it into an image, for instance by taking the median value, and do the calculations on that image:

```
var mosaic = dataset.median()
var nir = mosaic.select('B5')
var red = mosaic.select('B4')
var rvi = mosaic.divide(red)
```

Or you do the calculations on every image in the collection:

```
var rviCollection = dataset.map(function (image) {
  var nir = image.select('B5')
  var red = image.select('B4')
  var rvi = nir.divide(red).rename('rvi')
  return rvi
})
```